# How to get a return value from a recursive Groovy closure?

Tags: groovy, closures

i seem to have written a recursive closure :) difficult enough but i am not struggling on how to get feedback from this closure. My written closure deletes a file recursively from the a starting point on the filesystem. I want to now how many files have been deleted!

How can is get feedback on how many files i have deleted? I tried with delegate etc but no luck so far..

> ```
>     def deleteClosure
>     deleteClosure = {
>         it.eachDir( deleteClosure )
>         it.eachFileMatch( ~".*123.jpg" ) {
>             it.delete()
>         }
>     }
> ```

```
    deleteClosure(new File("/tmp/delete.me"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to write your own recursive closure code, Groovy adds an ***eachFileRecurse*** method to File objects.  To get a count of files deleted you can always just increment a counter:

```
import groovy.io.*

def filesDeletedCount = 0
new File('/tmp/delete.me').eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) {
    if (it.name ==~ /.*123.jpg$/) {
        it.delete()
        filesDeletedCount++
    }
}

println "Files deleted: ${filesDeletedCount}"
```

Comment: Note that, for education purposes, using the external counter would work in the original example as well.  But it's definitely better to use the built-in methods whenever possible.

Comment: Groovy keeps me getting amazed time after time! thanks very much for pointing me out! I implemented the mentioned suggestion and it works perfect!